# "divide left by right" shown instead of \frac

Tags: bug, mathjax

I was reviewing close votes when I got the following:

[image: divide left by right]

I clicked on the question, saw the correct version ("divide left by right" replaced by "\frac"), then clicked the "go back one page" button on Firefox 36.0.4 (Microsoft Windows XP Professional version 2002 Service Pack 3), then got the following:

[image: frac]

> Is this a known bug?

Comment: What might have happened is between the first time you loaded the question and when you clicked on the question, someone edited the question to improve the LaTeX.

Comment: @robjohn I don't think so. In the history of the close queue, I see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0vJKN.png), when I visit the [review item](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/384377), it shows up normal, the post was last edited in February.

Comment: @DanielFischer: then this might be the intermediate form returned quickly by MathJax before the final rendering. Unfortunately, it seems this MathJax is static and so the SE code needs to wait for MathJax to finish rendering.

Comment: I was just seeing this over here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221762/proof-that-a-frac1a-in-mathbbz-iff-a-pm1/1221770#1221771 and it has come and gone almost randomly.  I couldn't use mathbb or set membership symbols in my own answer without odd text being inserted, and another answer is using frac and getting the issue mentioned in this question.  But for a few minutes the issue was gone, but then an edit occurred and it's back again.  Very weird.